# Using systemd timer to change the background wallpaper

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer, wallpaper

I am trying to use systemd timers to change my background wallpaper and it doesn't seem to be doing what I want.

Blelow I have listed the relevant files and outputs that I have.

bgchange.timer

```
[Unit]
Description=Timer for background change

[Timer]
OnUnitActiveSec=10sec
OnActiveSec=5sec
OnBootSec=1sec
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

bgchange.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Change background image periodically

[Service]
Type=oneshot
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/home/emobe/scripts/changebg.sh
```

/home/emobe/scripts/changebg.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
feh --no-fehbg --bg-scale --randomize /home/emobe/Pictures/wallpapers/*
```

bgchange.timer status

```
● bgchange.timer - Timer for background change
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/bgchange.timer; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: active (waiting) since Fri 2023-01-06 09:33:44 GMT; 4h 12min ago
      Until: Fri 2023-01-06 09:33:44 GMT; 4h 12min ago
    Trigger: Fri 2023-01-06 13:46:24 GMT; 4s left
   Triggers: ● bgchange.service
```

systemctl list-timers

```
Fri 2023-01-06 17:39:24 GMT 3h 52min left Thu 2023-01-05 23:57:47 GMT 13h ago            updatedb.timer                   updatedb.service
Sat 2023-01-07 00:00:00 GMT 10h left      Fri 2023-01-06 00:00:01 GMT 13h ago            logrotate.timer                  logrotate.service
Sat 2023-01-07 00:00:00 GMT 10h left      Fri 2023-01-06 00:00:01 GMT 13h ago            shadow.timer                     shadow.service
Sat 2023-01-07 09:48:44 GMT 20h left      Fri 2023-01-06 09:48:44 GMT 3h 58min ago       systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer     systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
Sat 2023-01-07 09:54:52 GMT 20h left      Fri 2023-01-06 00:34:15 GMT 13h ago            man-db.timer                     man-db.service
Sat 2023-01-07 15:00:00 GMT 1 day 1h left Tue 2022-12-06 22:57:11 GMT 1 month 0 days ago pamac-cleancache.timer           pamac-cleancache.service
Thu 2023-01-12 08:45:44 GMT 5 days left   Thu 2023-01-05 23:57:47 GMT 13h ago            pamac-mirrorlist.timer           pamac-mirrorlist.service
Thu 2023-01-12 20:26:18 GMT 6 days left   Fri 2023-01-06 00:25:48 GMT 13h ago            archlinux-keyring-wkd-sync.timer archlinux-keyring-wkd-sync.service
-                           -             Fri 2023-01-06 13:46:53 GMT 74ms ago           bgchange.timer                   bgchange.service
```

Comment: @don_crissti Right, I thought it might have been something like that. I'll give it a go and see thanks!

Comment: @don_crissti This was exactly my issue. Can you put it as an answer that I needed to create it as a `user` unit as opposed to `system`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run those as user service/timer... You would then not need to set the `DISPLAY` in the service file e.g.

```
[Unit]
Description=Change background image periodically

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/emobe/scripts/changebg.sh
```

should be enough. `systemd` user files usually go in `~/.config/systemd/user/` so place them there

```
~/.config/systemd/user/bgchange.timer
~/.config/systemd/user/bgchange.service
```

then run as a regular user

```
systemctl --user daemon-reload
systemctl --user enable --now bgchange.timer
```

Check that the timer is active, always as `--user`:

```
systemctl --user list-timers
```

Comment: Just to be explicit: `systemctl --user` should never be run with `sudo`